# HTML - Enable Scrolling within a Table's Cell

Tags: html, scroll, html-table, cell

Let's say I have a table cell with fixed width and height.... and I have data that exceeds the cell's fixed dimensions...

```
<td width="500" height="300">lots of data that exceeds the dimensions</td>
```

- can I enable scrolling of this data within a cell....
- if not than what is the solution.. I only have that **500 x 300** space

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to add a 500 x 300 div and give it `overflow: auto`

```
<td width="500" height="300">
 <div style="width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: auto">
  lots of data that exceeds the dimensions
 </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I should have checked first, yes div inside should do the trick +1 :)