# Prevent TD from getting taller from content

Tags: html, css

I have a table, with cells receiving dynamic content. I want the cells to all have the same size, but no matter what I try I can't get my `td` with more content to stop growing taller and making all the other `tr`s smaller. I have `table-layout: fixed` with fixed width and heights but it's still not working.

Demo:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 30vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        abcdefg
      </div>
      <div>
        abcdefg
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(not exact code but a representation of what is happening).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question / answer here might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537734/html-enable-scrolling-within-a-tables-cell

Comment: @MatthewECornish I want it to just hide the overflow. Problem right now is the `td` is just growing taller instead of hiding.

Comment: cool - you can use the linked example and set the overflow-y property to hidden :)

Comment: @MatthewECornish I have `overflow:hidden` already enabled.

Comment: You need it for the div though, not its containing td element :) I don't think overflow is a valid CSS property for a table cell

Answer (score 0):

Table is an old technique used within HTML and CSS and therefore all the new CSS features doesn't work. Tried to set a max-height on your TD but it didn't work. Although you should focus on your TR instead of your TD as you should force the TR to be a set height, not the data within it.

Here's a work in progress: `https://jsfiddle.net/a4ew9ft5/1/`

```
tr {
  height: 30vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rethinking my answer now I notice you have two divs in the cell:** if you're going to have an unknown number of divs in your td that are 30vh in height then you will need a container, something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdQpvb

You will need to add **overflow** properties set to **hidden** for the 30vh high elements containing whatever content you have. Then set to **auto** for the container div element which will act as your td boundary (so then you can scroll through the elements, else... you'll not see many!).

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        Donec nunc diam, imperdiet quis quam ac, varius placerat nisi. Praesent nec nunc vel nisl tristique sollicitudin. Cras ut nibh a arcu faucibus fringilla. Maecenas rhoncus ipsum sit amet libero auctor egestas. Suspendisse dapibus egestas augue quis laoreet. Ut sed lectus eu felis ullamcorper pulvinar ut a ante. Aliquam euismod ut massa vel laoreet. Proin nunc leo, pellentesque at nulla in, iaculis commodo nulla.
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Sed eu libero vitae eros elementum vulputate. Proin finibus tincidunt lorem, a tempor nulla. Donec id metus eget velit consectetur bibendum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla interdum mauris libero, ac tempor leo finibus ac. Donec scelerisque vel turpis ac tincidunt. Curabitur ac ex sit amet ex mattis ultrices.
      </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 30vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.container{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div.content {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I feel this is making too great an assumption of what OP wants to achieve, based on too little information :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're trying to do is this. Place your `div` elements in a container with absolute positioning, and then make the overflow of your `td` elements to scroll.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 30vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container{
  position: absolute;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="div1">
          abcdefg
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
          abcdefg
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```